# How to fetch this data from the Firebase Database

Tags: java, regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an android app, it's data is stored in  the firebase database.
 `name=dataSnapshot.child(email).child(dt+" "+).getValue(Warden.class).getName();`
In this snippet I want to access the node from the database where the nodes are named as  : combination of current date and any number.

I am able to get the current date using Date class (using 'dt' variable), but I can't get the number, i.e I can't get the combination to search that node. I tried using regex, but couldn't do it.I want to get a string which starts with the current date and ends with a 3 digit number . please help me in this,
thanks in adavnce.

```
-Warden
   |-ahilyabhawan
   |-ashokbhawan
       |-Apr 18, 2018 339
           |-bhawan: "Ashok Bhawan"
           |-date: "May 6, 2018"
           |-gender: "Male"
           |-intime:"14 : 28 pm"
           |-mobile:"9785648810"
           |-room_no: "359"
           |-student_id: "Coer ID: 14041044"

       |-Apr 24, 2018 349
       |-May 1, 2018 129
       |-May 11, 2018 156
       |-May 2, 2018 223

      DateFormat df=DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
      dt=df.format(d);
  databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() 
  {     
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(email)){


                name=dataSnapshot.child(email).child(dt+" "+"?").getValue(Warden.class).getName();    //***** line 1 *****
                student_id=dataSnapshot.child(email).child(dt+" "+"?").getValue(Warden.class).getStudent_id();
                if(name!=null&&student_id!=null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    arrayList.add(dt + " \n" + name + "\n" + student_id);
                }


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that I want to access every of the child of "**ashokbhawan**" node which contains the current date  and any 3 digit number.
Now the thing is I am able to get the current date, but I need is a combination of current date and any 3 digit number. How can I get that?

Comment: You should give more info, in particular your database structure

Comment: You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @Codeninja Could you update your original post with this database structure in a formatted way?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the filtering capacity of the Firebase Real Time Database ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data)) and build a query like the following one and use the proper listener (see the doc, previous link):

```
Query query = databaseReference.child("posts").child("Warden/ashokbhawa").startAt('Apr 18, 2018').endAt('Apr 19, 2018');
```

Of course it's up to you to pass the correct values as variables.

---

Side note: I would suggest you store your dates as YYYYMMDD

Comment: Thanks a lot, @RenaudTarnec you saved the day!